# How to map different URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, https, dns, mapping

I need all my domains to have the https certificate, but when I created the .htaccess file, the website wen't down.

Here's the story:
I have a Ruby on Rails website let's call: web1.com.br

I also have the domains:  web1.com, web2.com.br and web2.com

I made the DNS mapping so whenever people type those 3 domains, they all go to my original host on web1.com.br (and not changing the url for the user) and it works fine.

But I don't have my https certificate when someone types the other 3 domains. Only on my original website web1.com.br I have the let's encrypt certificate

I asked my host provider for help and they told me to add to my www folder a .htaccess file but I probably did something wrong.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web1.com.br.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.web1.com.br%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web1\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.web1\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http\:\/\/www\.web1\.com\.br\/ [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web1.com.br.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.web1.com.br%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.web2\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http\:\/\/www\.web1\.com\.br\/ [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web1.com.br.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.web1.com.br%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web2\.com\.br$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.web2\.com\.br$
RewriteRule ^$ http\:\/\/www\.web1\.com\.br\/ [R=301,L]
```

I created the .htaccess file and my website (on all domains) went off, giving a 500 response:

```
"The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at web@web1.com.br to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."
```

I deleted the file and the site went back online

As you can probably tell, I'm a total noob but can't find someone to help me. I don't know if I did the .htaccess wrong or my hosting support gave me the wrong information.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but if you operate different hosts (host names, sometimes also called "domains" or "subdomains"), then you need different certificates. There is no way around that. No sane browser will accept a certificate that does not match the requested host name.

Answer (score 0):

Check this rules in your .htaccess file, redirect all to https://web1.com.br/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?web1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://web1.com.br/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?web2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://web1.com.br/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?web2\.com\.br [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://web1.com.br/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.web1\.com\.br [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://web1.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web1\.com\.br [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://web1.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
```